# How to overcome " Cannot open the mailbox for this user because the user does not have a server mailbox " COMException in outlook programming?

Tags: c#, outlook

I have developed a WPF based tool in .NET 4.5 in which I am trying to fetch information from emails in one of the outlook accounts. 
However I am getting runtime `COMException` with message `"Cannot open the mailbox for this user because the user does not have a server mailbox"`.
I know this happens when email accounts have different exchange servers.

Is there any way we can overcome this & access account which is on different exchange server?

Below is the code block which I am using to select particular account from multiple ones. `GetSharedDefaultFolder` is the method that is raising the exception:

```
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Account account in accounts)
{
    // When the e-mail address matches, return the account. 
    if (account.SmtpAddress.Contains("ABC.com"))
    {
        mapiNameSpace = myApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
        //selecting Inbox folder
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Recipient recipent =
            mapiNameSpace.CreateRecipient(account.SmtpAddress);
        recipent.Resolve();
        if (recipent.Resolved)
        {
            return mapiNameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(
                recipent,
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
        }
    }
}
```

I would be grateful if anyone could help.

Comment: Do you mean the user in a different domain?

Comment: @Dmitry Streblechenko - There are 2 Accounts set up in outlook. Both accounts belong to different companies, so yes different domains.

Comment: You will need to have a mailbox from that domain in your profile. Which Outlook method raises that error?

Comment: @Dmitry Streblechenko - Please refer to description for the answer of your question.

Comment: @Dmitry Streblechenko - Just tagging u to bring your attention, in case missed out my reply... :-)

Comment: I am not sure why you are using CreateRecipient / GetSharedDefaultFolder if the user's account is already present in the Accounts collection. Wouldn't it also be in the Stores collection?